# Android aar library with maven dependencies

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

I'm developing a `Java library` that needs to be used by both `Android` and traditional `Java Apps`.

I have 2 maven projects, a core module, and another that implements some interfaces (declared in the core module) with `retrofit2`. The code in this artifacts is pure Java. The only external dependency up to now is `retrofit` (and `gson-converter`).

In my android app, I have a library module that consumes those 2 artifacts from our maven repo. Here we also implement a couple of interfaces declared in the core module using android classes, there are no resources (`layouts`, `drawables`) in this module.

I tested the app and it works ok.

Now I want to build an `AAR` of this module and publish it to our maven repo. So that the guys working on the app can use it.

Maybe you could help with some questions:

- `Gradle` in not packing the jars inside the `AAR`. How can I do this? Is this the correct approach? Is there a standard way of doing this?
- Would it be a good idea to use [`simpligility/android-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin)?

My final goal is to integrated all in `jenkins`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can publish with Gradle without using any 3rd party plugins. Can you post your code from your `build.gradle` from your attempt to publish the `AAR`?

Comment: I can post it later. However my primary concern is if the best approach is to bundle the dependencies in a fat aar. Or if it is best for the final app to consume a "thin" aar and also the other jar via maven